# How to remove first brackets from list in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I write a query to get the list like this:

```
tStartEnd = APIHistory.objects.values('status_start','status_end')
codereview = list(tStartEnd)
```

expected output is: ['start', 'end']
but I'm getting : [('START', 'END')]

using django query how get the output like this

> ['start', 'end']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the items in the tuple:

```
tStartEnd = APIHistory.objects.values_list('status_start','status_end')
codereview = [item for q in tStartEnd for item in q]
```

This will thus enumerate over the records `q` in the queryset, and over the items in the tuple that `1` presents.